# Denormalized float number is detected as NaN. Why?

Tags: c, floating-point, nan

Currently, I am transmitting a denormalized float number = 0x00300000. Before this value is set for another variable, inequality (var != var) check is done i.e. check for NaN. The inequality check fails for the denormalized number and the number is detected as NaN.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? My code is in C.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the "a denormalized float number = 0x00300000"... Are you _absolutely_ sure that the floating point variable has that bit pattern as a value? What happens if you printf it?

Comment: Show us your code.  The (var != var) evaluation and NaN aren't normally seen in C code.  Javascript yes, but I'm confused about what you are doing in C.  So show us your code.

Comment: Could you give me a denormalized number in hex? I will try the same and see what is happening, in case I do not have a valid denormalized number. @Mysticial: Its the same number that is shown to me, but fails the inequality check. Has it anything to do with compiler setting?

Comment: I would imagine that denormalized floating point numbers will break the algorithms for mathematical operations as for efficency these algorithms assume that the operands are normalized. (by algorithms - i mean the hardware in the ALU)

Comment: Correction, it is a denormalized number. I was off by 1 bit in the exponent. But in any case I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It _is_ denormalised since the exponent bits are all zero.

Comment: What are your compiler and platform, how do you compile (i.e. with what options)?

Comment: @Alex: Compiler is gcc. We are using these options: -EB -N -g -v. Can you tell me which option is this dependent on? Or any other compiler setting that has to be made?

Answer (score 2):

The equality check seems fine on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0x00300000;
    float f = 0;
    if (sizeof(f) != sizeof(i)) {
        printf ("Urk!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    memcpy (&f, &i, sizeof(f));
    printf ("%.50f\n", f);
    if (f == f)
        puts ("Equal");
    else
        puts ("Not equal");
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000440810381558
Equal
```

Comment: Same here. In addition, if I use the value `0xFFFFFFFF` for i, it prints value NAN and "Not equal" as expected. So my guess is that the value in the question does not have the value the OP expects it to have.

Comment: I guess it has to do something with the compiler options or settings.